# Show and Hide functions using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new for jquery, Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.toAdd').hide();

                var count = 0;
                $('#add').on('click', function () {
                    $('.toAdd:eq(' + count + ')').show();
                    count++;
                });
            });

</script>
<div class="toAdd">One</div><div class="toAdd">Two</div><div class="toAdd">Three</div>
<input type="button" value="show" id="add"/>
<input type="button" value="hide" id="sub"/>
```

In this code if i click show button the divisions one by one it showing. after that i need to hide one by one if i click hide button

Fiddle [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/MkdTc/)

Comment: And what have you tried already?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.toAdd').show();

                var count > 0;
                $('#sub').on('click', function () {
                    $('.toAdd:eq(' + count + ')').hide();
                    count--;
                });
            }); like that i tried but its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this might help you... :)

```
                 $('#sub').on('click', function () {
                        if(count > 0){
                           count--;
                        $('.toAdd:eq(' + count + ')').hide();
                        }

                    });
```

Comment: <script>$(document).ready(function () {
                $('.toAdd').hide();

                var count = 0;
                $('#add').on('click', function () {
                    $('.toAdd:eq(' + count + ')').show();
                    count++;
                });

                $('#sub').on('click', function () {
                    count--;
                    $('.toAdd:eq(' + count + ')').hide();

                });
            });
        </script>

Comment: please do check the value of the counts.I have edited the code,so that the count variable is decremented only if the value is greater than 0

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toAdd').hide();

    var count = 0;
    $('#add').on('click', function () {
        $('.toAdd:eq(' + count + ')').show();
        count++;
    });
    var deCount = count;
    $('#sub').on('click', function () {
        count--;
        $('.toAdd:eq(' + count + ')').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this too

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.toAdd').hide();

                $('#add').on('click', function () {
                    $('.toAdd,.hidden').first().show().addClass( "shown" ).removeClass( "hidden" );
                });
                $('#sub').on('click', function () {
                    $('.toAdd,.shown').last().hide().addClass( "hidden" ).removeClass( "shown" );
                });
            });
```

Comment: Are you aware of [jquery chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp)

Comment: @gowri I wasn't. But now I am. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Edited jsfiddle by **Outlooker**

```
if($('.toAdd:eq(' + count + ')').is('*'))
```

Added check of item existance.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MkdTc/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Outlooker is right but have some little bit error. `when user will click on show button 4th time then your hide doesn't work as expected`. So I just fix the chunk here and sharing with you guys.

**Html Code:**

```
<div class="toAdd">One</div>
<div class="toAdd">Two</div>
<div class="toAdd">Three</div>
<input type="button" value="show" id="add" />
<input type="button" value="hide" id="sub" />
```

**Java Script Code:**

```
/**
 * Hide all Content div
 */
$(".toAdd").hide();
/**
 * Total no of content div find out
 **/
var lengthDiv = $(".toAdd").length;
/**
 * Default count declare
 **/
var count = 0;
/**
 * Click on show button
 **/
$('#add').on('click', function () {
    if (count < lengthDiv) {
        $('.toAdd:eq(' + count + ')').show();
        count++;
    }
});
/**
 * Click on hide button
 **/
$('#sub').on('click', function () {
    if (count > 0) {
        count--;
        $('.toAdd:eq(' + count + ')').hide();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rjvr/C2XUr/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this this will work you very fine

```
    $('.toAdd').hide();
    $('#add').click(function(){
    $('div').each(function(key, value) {

            $(value).delay(key * 500).fadeIn(500);

        });});
        $('#sub').click(function(){
        $('div').each(function(key, value) {

            $(value).delay(key * 500).fadeOut(500);

        });
});
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Pj2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $toAdds = $('.toAdd').hide();

var count = 0;
$('#add').on('click', function () {
    if (count < $toAdds.length) {
        $toAdds.eq(count).show();
        count++;
    }
});
$('#sub').on('click', function () {
    if (count > 0) {
        count--;
        $toAdds.eq(count).hide();
    }    
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vQvhF/)